# iCal always show RSVP on Yahoo / OutLook

Tags: php, outlook, gmail, icalendar, yahoo-mail

I am sending a calendar `ics` file in an email, as an attachment, that I send through the system.

I don't want the user to see the **RSVP** buttons. I just want the event to be their calendar.

So I use the below to generate iCal using `PHP`.

***Note***: text within **{{** and **}}** are my variables.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:{{20170108T131000Z}}
DTEND:{{20170108T132500Z}}
DTSTAMP:{{20170108T131000Z}}
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{{my_email@domain.com}}
URL;VALUE=URI:{{domain.com/123456}}
UID:{{123456}}
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=CHAIR;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=FALSE;CN={{ParticipantName}};X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:{{participant@gmail.com}}
DESCRIPTION:{{Description test \n Line1 \n Line 3}}
LOCATION:{{Location information \n Line1 \n Line2}}
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:{{Summary text}}
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Once I send this to Gmail it does not show the RSPV buttons. But if I send the same mail to Yahoo OR Outlook it always display the RSVP buttons.

I set the,

1. **STATUS** to **CONFIRMED** in **VEVENT**
2. **PARTSTAT** to **ACCEPTED** and **RSVP** to **FALSE** in **ATTENDEE**

Can anybody help me to figure out why I see the RSVP buttons even with the above settings?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone came across with this kind of a situation?